# Why does OpenShift oc new-app only sometimes schedule builds

Tags: openshift

I have two OpenShift 3.10 applications with proprietary templates. For one, `oc new-app --template=app1` automatically schedules a build. For the other, `oc new-app --template=app2` does not schedule builds, and manual invocations of `oc start-build` are required. (`app1` contains one `BuildConfig` wheras `app2` contains two, and the orders of objects inside the two templates are different.)

What makes OpenShift behave in different ways with respect to scheduling builds in such circumstances?

**UPDATE** I'm quite sure it does not depend on the number of `BuildConfig`s alone, for I've meanwhile also encountered an application with a single such component where `oc new-app` does not automatically schedule the build.

Comment: What triggers do you have defined in the build and deployment configs for each?

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thx for the lead. I think I've now been able to figuring this out myself after closely inspecting all of my triggers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to resolve this by cleaning up triggers in my build configurations (see `oc explain bc.spec.triggers`). They now look as follows:

```
triggers:
- type: ConfigChange
- type: Generic
  generic:
    allowEnv: false
    secretReference:
      name: webhook
```

`oc new-app`s for both apps now trigger builds; this is apparently caused by the triggers of type  `ConfigChange`.